# HTML+CSS: Unwanted space between TDs after word-wrapping

Tags: html, css, whitespace, word-wrap

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" height="13" style="color: #ff8000;font-weight: normal;vertical-align:top;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height: 18px;">
      &rsaquo;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td valign="top" height="13" style="font-weight: normal;vertical-align:top;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height: 18px;">
      <a style="padding-left: 10px;color:#4D4D4D;font-family:  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;font-size: 13px;text-decoration: none;" th:href="${n.desktopUrl}" th:utext="${n.headline}">
    Long long long text which will be wrapped
   </a>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" height="13" style="display: inline;padding-left: 10px;">Button code</td>

  </tr>
```

In the result I get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4LPW.png)

How to avoid this space after word-wrapping?

Comment: I'd take a look at the "padding-left: 10px" attribute you have.  I believe that does add space between the text and the cell border.

Comment: UPD: It is actually not a space between TDs - it is unwanted space in the second TD. And I cannot find how to adjust TD width to text after word-wrapping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THere is a `padding-left: 10px` on the `<td>` elements - this is what is causing the large gap

Answer (score 0):

```
<td valign="top" height="13" style="display: inline;padding-left: 0px;">Button code</td>
```

Set the value of `padding-left` to 0.